# Different layout for mobile phone and tablet

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want develop android xamarin app for mobile phone and tablets. I would like to know how to go about it?

I searched and I found that creating separate layout files would help. But does that mean that for each and every page I would have to add two layouts?

For mobile phone I would like to have two separate rows for mobile and FAX whereas for table I would like to adjust these in a single row something like this:

**Mobile phone design:**

[image]

**Tablet design:**

[image]

How can I get this?

Comment: Yes, you need to create another layout in the folder layout-600dp (for tablet with density starting at 600dp) and keep the same file name for both layouts.

Comment: @SofianeHassaini I am confused here. I created  layout-w600dp folder for tablet, but even when I run it on a emulator for Galaxy nexus it takes table layout. Why is that?

Comment: can you post here your layouts ?