# Multiple layouts for tablet and phone

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am developing an android app for **tablet** and **phone**. So to achieve that I created two folders on for phone(`layout`) and one for tablet layouts(`layout-sw600dp`).

As per my previous questions [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653996/different-layout-for-mobile-phone-and-tablet?noredirect=1#comment82266214_47653996) I assumed that only tablets would pick up layouts from `layout-sw600dp`. But it does not seem to work.

For `nexus 4, nexus 5, nexus 6, nexus 7` devices it is taking `layout-sw600dp` layout.

What am I missing here? How do I calculate phone/tablet size to proper `DP` layouts?

Required designs for tablet and phone:

[image]

Another retirement to use two separate layouts:

Phone design:

[image]

Tab design:

[image]

In response to the answered post below[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47785672/1650891), I have a linear layout like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayouttest">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="LabelFirstName"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:id="@+id/firstNameLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="LabelLastName"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:id="@+id/lastNameLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I change the orientation the textviews are not visible. Any solution to this?

Comment: instead of creating multiple layout you can achieve that thing by using different dimens file..Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524010/can-we-make-one-layout-type-for-all-screen-size/47524265#47524265).

Comment: I tried that, but it would not work because I have different designs for phone and table. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/intuit/sdp library to set view dimensions as per all devices (phone & tablet). It will automatically resize as per device screen size. set it as below :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_username"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_45sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
    android:text="@string/chat"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

**UPDATE**

First Check device is whether a phone or tablet using [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

or you can use below method to determine

```
public boolean isTablet() {
try {
    // Compute screen size
    DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;
    float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;
    double size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) + Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));
    // Tablet devices should have a screen size greater than 6 inches
    return size >= 6;

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

}

Then set parent LinearLayout orientation programatically as below :

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    ll.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
} else {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    ll.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
}
```

**XML CORRECTION**

Your layout must like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayouttest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstNameLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="LabelFirstName"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastNameLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="LabelLastName"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my edited question. I need different design for phone and tablet

Comment: Lets guess you are set 25sdp of editText textSize for HDPI device then It will automatically resize your layouts as per other device size

Comment: Will two texViews fit in one row for tablet using this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if I have two textviews? If in a phone layout the textvies should line one below other center aligned and in tab layout one has to align at left and one to right?

Comment: please check new update "XML CORRECTION" for your XML file correction

Answer (score 0):

Basically xxhdpi and xhdpi is for 5" to 5"5' devices. For Tablets you can use

> sw600dp
>
> sw600dp-tvdpi
>
> sw720dp
>
> sw720dp-mdpi
>
> sw720dp-xhdpi

. I have been working on this and these are the values which tabs takes. Try once. hope it will work.

Comment: Does that mean I have to create sw600dp,sw600dp-tvdpi,sw720dp,sw720dp-mdpi,sw720dp-xhdpi folders?

Comment: yes you have to create directory like values-sw600dp-tvdpi,values-sw600dp etc. and then you have to put dimens...

Comment: one more thing these values directory must be created under res directory, not under values or layout.

Comment: I am confused. I need to create dimens xml in all these folders? That I have created already. My question was for tablet layout which folder I need to put layout?

Comment: listen you need to create dimen.xml under all this folder. suppose in your value's folder dimen you have a key like  <dimen 
 name="imgwidth">150dp</dimen> , then put same key on every dimen.xml which you are using in rest of the dimen.xml and set the values accordig to your need